# Taking a Partial Derivate Under Integral

Tags: integration, derivatives

I am solving an optimization problem, and I have come to this function:

$\int\int U(f(x,y))g(x,y)dxdy - \lambda\int\int V(f(x,y))g(x,y)dxdy = 0$

I want to take a derivative w.r.t f(x,y)

Here's what I've written, but not certain if is all correct:

$\int\int [U'(f(x,y))g(x,y) + U(f(x,y))\frac{\partial g} {\partial f}] dxdy - \lambda \int\int [V'(f(x,y)g(x,y) + V(f(x,y)\frac{\partial g} {\partial f}] dxdy $

I am not sure whether I need to take g to f partial derivative or not in this context. Especially when I compare my F.O.C with the text, it seems to me that the second term should not be there. Can you please let me know the correct way of this derivation?

Update:
Thanks to the comments, the FOC should be written as:
$\int\int [U'(f(x,y))g(x,y)dxdy - \lambda \int\int [V'(f(x,y)g(x,y)dxdy $

Comment: From the way this is written I believe that your original problem has inputs $U,V,g$ and that these are given. So when you look at the integral equality for various $f$ these three functions still don't depend on $f$, so when you work out what happens as $f$ changes to $f+\eta$ this doesn't affect $U,V,g$: so there's no question of "differentiating $g$ wrt $f$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thanks, exactly my question. So even though g and f both are functions of x and y, there is no need for the second term, am I correct?

Comment: Yes: the point is that $g$ is a fixed function. It may take different values at different points but remains the same function.  [You really need to be precise in how you describe your problem. If you  just start it by writing down the integral equality some people might say "hey, but what if $g=f^2$" You need to put in the context to stop that misinterpretation. And the thing you call a functions is not, it's an equality. The function you want to differentiate is $f\mapsto \int\int U(f(x,y))g(x,y)dxdy -\lambda$ etc etc.

Comment: @ancientmathematician All clear. Many thanks